# Android studio, Java code showing in red. It is showing setup jdk ( for the code)

Tags: java, android

Here is the [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNEQF.jpg).
Recently I updated my android studio to android studio 4.Then suddenly today the Java code is underlined red and when I hovered  over the code(or click the bulb icon) it showed “setup JDK”.I even tried reinstalling android studio as well as the JDK(updated it to JDK14).

Comment: You haven't attach the image of your error. Please attach it since it will be helpful to others to answer you.

Comment: The OP didnt format correctly hence if u click on edit you can get the link to the image @KalanaChinthaka

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache and Restart. If not try file -> invalidate cache and restart. Might work.